# Bypassing metamask notice about "Insufficient funds for gas"

Tags: metamask, gas-price, transfer

I wish to make a transfer of the remaining ETH from one wallet to an other.
Trying to do it from metamask, it prevents me to do so with the "Insufficient funds for gas" error. Event though it doesn't know what gas price I will apply and so couldn't know what is sufficient or not.

How to get to the next step and be able to set my own gas price ? With, of course, the overall (sending amount + max gas fee) under the total amount owned by the account.

Update : strange thing is that on the Polygon network I have the gas price form on the same page as the one to set the amount to send, so the calculation can be well done based on the chosen price. However it doesn't display with the Ethereum network selected. Is it expected that metamask behaves differently depending on the network ?